# How to extract useful information from TransformerException

Tags: java, exception, xslt

I am using `javax.xml.transform.*` to do XSLT transformation. Since the xslt file to be used comes from the outside world there could be errors in that file, and I am going to give back some meaningful response to the user.

Although I can easily catch the `TransformationException`s, I found no way to obtain enough information from it. For example, if there is a tag to be terminated by an end-tag, `printStackTrace()` gives scarring message

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesheet
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(Unknown Source)
    ... (100 lines)
```

and `getMessage()` gives only

```
Could not compile stylesheet
```

None of them gives the real reason of the error.

I noticed that in Eclipse test console I can see the following

```
[Fatal Error] :259:155: The element type "sometag" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</sometag>".
ERROR:  'The element type "sometag" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</sometag>".'
FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
```

This is exactly what I want. Unfortunately, since this is a web application, the user cannot see this.

How can I display the correct error message to the user?

Comment: You can't really. If you want that run a validation step.....

Comment: Isn't the reason in the cause exception?

Comment: @agad Unfortunatelly the `getCause()` call returns `null`.

Comment: @EarthEngine What about getOriginalException()?

Comment: @agad There is no such method in either `TransformerException` or `TransformerConfigurationException`.

Answer (score 1):

Put your own [`ErrorListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/ErrorListener.html) on your `Transformer` instance using [`Transformer.setErrorListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html#setErrorListener%28javax.xml.transform.ErrorListener%29), like so:

```
final List<TransformationException> errors = new ArrayList<TransformationException>();
Transformer transformer = ... ;
transformer.setErrorListener(new ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void error(TransformerException exception) {
        errors.add(exception);
    }

    @Override
    public void fatalError(TransformerException exception) {
        errors.add(exception);
    }

    @Override
    public void warning(TransformerException exception) {
        // handle warnings as well if you want them
    }
});

// Any other transformer setup

Source xmlSource = ... ;
Result outputTarget = ... ;
try {
    transformer.transform(xmlSource, outputTarget);
} catch (TransformerException e) {
    errors.add(e); // Just in case one is thrown that isn't handled
}
if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    // Handle errors
} else {
    // Handle output since there were no errors
}
```

This will log all the errors that occur into the `errors` list, then you can use the messages off those errors to get what you want. This has the added benefit that it will try to resume the transformation after the errors occur. If this causes any problems, just rethrow the exception by doing:

```
@Override
public void error(TransformerException exception) throws TransformationException {
    errors.add(exception);
    throw exception;
}

@Override
public void fatalError(TransformerException exception) throws TransformationException {
    errors.add(exception);
    throw exception;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's likely that any solution will dependent on your choice of XSLT processor. Different implementations of the JAXP interface might well provide different information in the exceptions they generate.

It's possible that the error from the XML parser is available in a wrapped exception. For historic reasons, TransformerConfigurationException offers both getException() and getCause() to access wrapped exceptions, and it may be worth checking them both.

Alternatively it's possible that the information was supplied in a separate call to the ErrorListener.

Finally, this particular error is detected by the XML parser (not the XSLT processor) so in the first instance it will be handled by the parser. It may well be worth setting the parser's ErrorHandler and catching parsing errors at that level. If you want explicit control over the XML parser used by the transformation, use a SAXSource whose XMLReader is suitably initialized.

Answer (score -1):

You can configure System.out to write in your own OutputStream. 
Use of ErrorListener don't catch all output.
If you work with threads you can look here (http://maiaco.com/articles/java/threadOut.php) to avoid change of System.out for other threads.

example

```
public final class XslUtilities {
    private XslUtilities() {
        // only static methods
    }

    public static class ConvertWithXslException extends Exception {
        public ConvertWithXslException(String message, Throwable cause) {
            super(message, cause);
        }
    }

    public static String convertWithXsl(String input, String xsl) throws ConvertWithXslException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream systemOutByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PrintStream oldSystemOutPrintStream = System.out;
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(systemOutByteArrayOutputStream));

        ByteArrayOutputStream systemErrByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PrintStream oldSystemErrPrintStream = System.err;
        System.setErr(new PrintStream(systemErrByteArrayOutputStream));

        String resultXml;
        try {
            System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory", "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xsl)));
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new StringReader(input)), new StreamResult(stringWriter));
            resultXml = stringWriter.toString();
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            System.out.flush();
            final String systemOut = systemOutByteArrayOutputStream.toString();
            System.err.flush();
            final String systemErr = systemErrByteArrayOutputStream.toString();

            throw new ConvertWithXslException("TransformerException - " + e.getMessageAndLocation()
                            + (systemOut.length() > 0 ? ("\nSystem.out:" + systemOut) : "")
                            + (systemErr.length() > 0 ? ("\nSystem.err:" + systemErr) : ""), e);
        } finally {
            System.setOut(oldSystemOutPrintStream);
            System.setErr(oldSystemErrPrintStream);
        }

        return resultXml;
    }
}
```

Comment: What output won't it catch? All he wants is the error. This is a lot of overkill for that. Plus what if his server outputs something else while this is running because it's a multi-threaded system? The user will see that output in the message they get with the error. This isn't a good solution.

Comment: depends from transformer engine some (helpful) output goes to System.out. unfortunaly ErrorListener don't catch this.

Comment: to avoid catch of other thread output use maiaco solution. thats great.